# Gazebo model jittering

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi, I managed to finally catch up with all the great development happening. I have put my model on this repository in the ales_description/models/ales_robot folder.
https://bitbucket.org/TheLegace/ales_robot/overview

I had made joints for my four wheeled robot, but for some reason it seems to be moving or jitterring on its own. It's noticeable and I am assuming the pose is changing. There is no plug in enabled so I cannot for the life of me understand why the model is moving.

If you would like me to upload the model anywhere else please let me know.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1363/gazebo-model-jittering/) by [Vaibhav Kapoor](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/212/vaibhav-kapoor/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 36 on 2013-02-13

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2013-02-13**:
You could change the link to point directly to the model file, it's faster for others to look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi I had started removing every single component until the jitterring had stopped. The very first link was even jitterring, I realized that maybe it's the inertia's that I had not setup yet. So I just put some reasonable values and it looks like the model is not jitterring any longer.

I also had to make sure the wheels had inertia as well, also the high friction coefficient that I got from the Golf Cart vehicle.

Thank you.

---

Originally posted by [Vaibhav Kapoor](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/212/vaibhav-kapoor/) with karma: 36 on 2013-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1